# Reader Applicative's Apply Function

Tags: haskell

Looking at the `reader or environment applicative` from Brent Yorgey's UPenn 2013 [Lecture](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures/11-applicative2.html):

```
instance Functor ((->) e) where
  fmap = (.)

instance Applicative ((->) e) where
  pure = const
  f <*> x = \e -> (f e) (x e)
```

I'm trying to gain intuition for the Applicative instance.

Given:

`(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`

then how does `\e -> (f e) (x e)` result in the `f b` type?

Answer (score 8):

If we substitute `((->) e)` for `f` (remembering that this is a function with `e` as its argument type), we get:

```
(<*>) ::     f    (a -> b)  ->    f     a  ->    f    b
(<*>) :: ((->) e) (a -> b)  -> ((->) e) a  -> ((->) e) b  -- Replace f with ((->) e)
(<*>) ::    (e -> (a -> b)) ->    (e -> a) ->    (e -> b) -- Apply ((->) e)
(<*>) ::    (e ->  a -> b)  ->    (e -> a) ->     e -> b  -- Remove unneeded parentheses
```

A key thing to remember is that `((->) e) a` is the same as `e -> a`. The notation can look a bit misleading at first.

The only implementation for this type is the one you have provided in your question. This definition can also be written as:

```
f <*> x = \e -> f e (x e)
```

or, using prefix notation:

```
(<*>) f x e = f e (x e)
```

Answer (score -2):

Looks like S combinator to me. (It's not an answer, it's a comment.)

My explanation is this:

Applicative operation is pretty much like zipping. In our specific case we have two entities (`f` and `a`) that both depend on `e`. So zipping them together produces another entity that depends on e again: and when called, it uses the same e for the left and for the right part. Compare to this:

We have f<sub>0</sub>, f<sub>1</sub>, f<sub>2</sub>, etc, and a<sub>0</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, etc. When zipping them, we get (f<sub>0</sub>,a<sub>0</sub>), (f<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>1</sub>), (f<sub>2</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>) etc.

In applicative case, we also apply `fi` to `ai`, so we get (f<sub>0</sub> a<sub>0</sub>), (f<sub>1</sub> a<sub>1</sub>), (f<sub>2</sub> a<sub>2</sub>) etc. Note that we use the same index for `f` and `a`. If we consider the index as environment (we "read" the index), here we go, it's the same thing. And also, that's how S combinator works.

Comment: This is true, but how does it answer the question?

Comment: That looks like it mostly explains the `ZipList` instance of `Applicative` specifically. It doesn't seem to apply so much to many of the other instances: `[]` and `Const a` come to mind. I'm also not sure how that fits with `(->) e`. It looks like you're saying that each `ai` gets applied to a corresponding index but, as you said later, with `(->) e` the index stays the same.